# How to launch a .wzmul file through batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I have a script to install WinZip on users computers, however, I need to move a `.wzmul` file into the correct location, I've done all of this successfully but when I try to launch the file with the `start` command it will just launch another cmd.

```
@echo off

set winzip_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\WinZip\WinZip15
set exec_name=winzip150.msi
set reg_name=WinZip.wzmul
set reg_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip"

pushd %winzip_path%

xcopy "%winzip_path%\%exec_name%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop"
msiexec /i "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%exec_name%" /QN /L*V "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\winzip_log.txt"
@echo "DONE!!"
xcopy "%winzip_path%\%reg_name%" %reg_path%
start /wait %reg_path%\%reg_name%
```

How do I open this kind of file correctly?

Comment: You don't run it.  You just copy it to the install path.

Comment: Here's our manual installation instructions: `copy to desktop the \\mgtutils01\Windows7Apps\WinZip15 folder 

run winzip150.msi to install the application 

Uncheck Open application 


copy winzip.wzmul  C:\Program Files\WinZip folder 

Go to C:\Program Files\WinZip folder and double click winzip.wzmul 

Click Yes to register`

Comment: I have never done it that way. The first Winzip is launched it will register itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the _installation instructions_ an format it to a readable form (as you can see, comments can't be formatted properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience the first time you launch Winzip the program will do the registration if the multilicense exists in the program directory.  But essentially you have some problems with your batch file because of the way you are quoting your paths.  Best practice is to not assign quotes in your variables but do use quotes to protect spaces and special characters in your variables.  Basically the START command is seeing the quotes as the Window TITLE.  So these changes to your batch file should work. You are also using PUSHD to the Winzip path so you do not need to specify the Winzip path in your code.  It is already the working directory.

```
@echo off

set "winzip_path=\\mgtutils01\windows7apps\WinZip\WinZip15"
set "exec_name=winzip150.msi"
set "reg_name=WinZip.wzmul"
set "reg_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\WinZip"

pushd "%winzip_path%"

xcopy "%exec_name%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
msiexec /i "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%exec_name%" /QN /L*V "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\winzip_log.txt"
@echo "DONE!!"
xcopy "%reg_name%" "%reg_path%\"
start "" /wait "%reg_path%\%reg_name%"

POPD
```